# Proving geometric inequality with algebra

Tags: inequality

Geometrically, since a straight line is the shortest path from a point to another:
$$\sum\sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2}\le \sqrt{\left(\sum x_i\right)^2+\left(\sum y_i\right)^2}$$
Where $x_i,y_i$ are positive reals, and equality occurs when
$$\frac{x_i}{y_i}=\frac{\sum x_i}{\sum y_i}$$
That is, all the points lie in the line. But ¿How would we prove it algebraically? The fact that we need that one sequence is a multiple of another makes me think in Cauchy-Shwarz, but I have no other interesing ideas about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By squaring both sides we have that the inequality (with the right direction, $\geq$) is equivalent to:
$$\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{(x_i^2+y_i^2)(x_j^2+y_j^2)}\geq \sum_{i\neq j}(x_i x_j+y_i y_j)$$
that follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thank you! I think I wasn't brave enough to dare square it...